# Fancytree and Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui

I have been looking at this [Fancytree](http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/) examples and I would like to use that in my angular application. My question is how do I pass data from my angular Controller to this tree and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

A simple controller cannot achieve this, you'll need to have a directive to manipulate the DOM. For instance, you can do it in link function:

```
        link : function(scope, element){
            element.fancytree({
                source: [
                    {title: "Node 1", key: "1"},
                    {title: "Folder 2", key: "2", folder: true, children: [
                        {title: "Node 2.1", key: "3"},
                        {title: "Node 2.2", key: "4"}
                    ]}
                ],
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am having some problem with fancyrtee + Angularjs.. It look likes that when I click on a fancytree item, it does not go in the controller...

So, now I am using this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-fancytree